# Setting multiple visual states in one go?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visualstatemanager, visualstates

I have four visual states defined each affecting different child controls within the same silver-light control.
Is it possible for me to create other visual states which invoke a combination of these others?

> So if I have **Visual_Group_1, Visual_Group_2, Visual_Group_3, Visual_Group_4**

1. Is it possible to make, say a
   Visual_Comb_1 group which uses the
   states in Visual_Group_1 and
   Visual_Group_3?
2. Then make another one called Visual_Comb_2 which uses Visual_Group_4 and Visual_Group_3?

I'm happy to implement a `solution in xaml or codebehind or a combination of both`.
The alternative I'm looking at currently involves tonnes of code copy+paste and I'm not too keen to do that.

Some more detail per request:

This is what I roughly have right now:

```
<VisualState x:Name="State1">
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path1"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="Blue" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    // fade out the rest of the paths...
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path2"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="#00000000" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path3"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="#00000000" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path4"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="#00000000" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
</VisualState>

<VisualState x:Name="State2">
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path3"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    // fade out the rest of the paths...
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path2"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="#00000000" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path1"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="#00000000" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path4"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="#00000000" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
</VisualState>

<VisualState x:Name="State3">
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path4"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="Pink" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    // fade out the rest of the paths...
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path2"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="#00000000" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path1"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="#00000000" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path3"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    To="#00000000" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
</VisualState>
```

My objective is to have a control which when you click on cycles from state1 to state3, each state fades in a different path while fading out the other paths. My problem is that there is a tonne of copy+paste in the 'fade out the rest of the paths' section, so if I wanted to add a Path5 it would mean adding it to every single visual state already defined, or if I wanted to change the fadeoff colour or animation I would have to do it to every visual state.

Comment: I'm hoping I can help, but with the problem description you've provided, it's rather difficult to develop a concrete understanding of what exactly you want to happen.
Is it possible to post the basic XAML structure, so that we can see where within the visual tree the `VisualStates` are implemented, and have you provide a concrete example of what you want to happen. (Eg. I want to click this button, and then have 'Control A' enter this visual state, 'Control B' enter this state and all the rest enter some other state.)

Comment: I just added some xaml to show what I'm currently doing and how I hope to improve said code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for providing the XAML.  This is how I would tackle the problem.

First off, create the `VisualStates` individually for each `Path`.  (I would recommend using a `Style` instead to save you re-coding a very similar `VisualState` into each Path, but I'm not familiar enough with them to know if you can apply different colours to each.)

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Path1States">
        <VisualState x:Name="Activate">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path1"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="Blue"
                                Duration="0:0:0.5" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Deactivate">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Path1"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="#00000000"
                                Duration="0:0:0.5" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Path2States">
        <!-- ... etc ... -->
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Now, create a `List` in the code-behind that contains each of the related objects, and then right your own `GoToState` function such that it turns on the in state for one object, and calls the off state for the rest.

```
List<Path> pathList;

public Page() // constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pathList = new List<Path>();
    pathList.Add(Path1);
    // and so forth
}

// Call this function when you want to change the state
private void ActivatePath(Path p)
{
    foreach (Path listItem in pathList)
    {
        // If the item from the list is the one you want to activate...
        if (listItem == p)
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(listItem, "Activate", true);
        // otherwise...
        else
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(listItem, "Deactivate", true);
    }
}
```

If I were better at XAML and styling I might have a cleaner way of creating the VisualStates.  However, my forte is more on the logic and coding side.  That being said, it's much cleaner that writing out the same `VisualState` four or five times! :)
Hope this helps!